# Simulating a compass with 3-axis accelerometer readouts (for use in Android apps that require a compass)

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, compass-geolocation, magnetometer

I have a 3-axis accelerometer in my mobile phone but no magnetometer. Is it possible to simulate a compass with accelerometer readouts? If so, is there an app that can be installed on an android device or script of some kind that can use data from the accelerometer to simulate a compass (i.e. create a virtual compass that can be consumed by Android apps that require a compass)?

Answer (score 1):

short answer - no

With accelerometer you can get only accelerations around 3 axes but you want to make a compass which shows north.

If you combine accelerometer readings with gyroscope readings you can find orientation changes of the phone but you still can not simulate a compass because you don't have a reference point. (Here if you have an anchor point in world coordinate system and if you able to detect it with mobile device you can get relative position with the help of accelerometer + gyroscope but in practice it is harder to implement than magnetometer)

Comment: I'm wondering whether if you know where North is and you hold your phone upright and perpendicular to North, and then set the app to make this the reference point, whether it will be possible to simulate a compass using only 3-axis accelerometers.

Comment: In that case (if you have a reference point) it is possible if there is no linear acceleration, if there is no linear acceleration accelerometer only reads gravity value and you will get gravity vector, and if you have another vector that shows north you can imitate a compass

Comment: but if you have linear acceleration (if you are moving) your accelerometer data is now include linear acceleration and gravity together and it is really hard to separate this two different vector. But still in that case if you have a vector showing north it is possible to imitate compass